# The getBuiltInScopes method was not found

Tags: coldfusion

I have an application that has worked for quite a while.  I have made no changes to the code since the last time I used it.  Basically, the code creates a zip file with input for an involved report.  I used it in March of this year it worked fine.  I've been assured by the gov't sysadmins and DBAs that nothing has changed, but I still get the attached error.  Any ideas?

[image]

*Environment:* Oracle 10.2 ColdFusion front end

Comment: So I take it I've stumped everyone?  Is this something I should already know?  I do not.  Please help if you can.

Comment: Insanity...  I have two servers; one Production and one Test.  Just for giggles, I updated the Test database to mirror Production.  the code is all up to date.   I now attempt to run the application that gives me the above error and I get Error 13xx - Event handler exception (the number increases by one for each error I get.  Any ideas?

Comment: I am not that well versed in ColdFusion or Java.  I am basically an Oracle DBA.   I get this error when attempting to create and download a file in my application.  Not sure what this is, but it could cost me my job.  Any one that can give me a clue, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Still haven't figured this out and don't have a clue where to look.

Comment: Am I asking in the wrong spot?

Comment: This has now popped up in another portion of the application, not associated with the action performed for the original. Any ideas? I am a ColdFusion/Java novice.

Comment: Could this be related to the version of ColdFusion I am using?  I am currently using 8.  If my customer updated their version to anything above that, I understand this is not supported.  Any ideas?

Comment: Quite possibly, yes. `getBuiltInScopes()` is not a standard CF function. Its use is discouraged in prod code because it is an undocumented method. ie It could change, or be removed entirely, at any time - without warning. But for anyone to help, you need to post some code. Start by looking at the *.CFM script throwing the error. Search the file for `getBuiltInScopes` and post the relevant code lines. Also, what is your current CF version? If you do not know it, run a dump:  `<cfdump var="#server.coldfusion#">`.

Comment: I'm running 8.   I see from a search that getBuiltInScopes() is getCFScopes() in 9...    I am having trouble posting code, sorry.  Basically, it just has this in the body of html `<cfdump var="#getPageContext().getBuiltInScopes()#"/>`

Comment: that is the only place it appears when I use AstroGrep.

Comment: That looks like a simple debugging line. Try commenting it out. (BTW, CF is *not* case sensitive, so be sure to account for that in your search expressions). That said, Did you look at the .cfm script actually throwing the error?  Also, that function shouldn't throw an error under CF8. AFAIK, it wasn't removed until CF9. So are you *positive* about your version ...?

Comment: It doesn't happen on my development box, which is at CF8.  The Production box, however, is at CF10.  Production is where the error is showing up.   Right now, I am awaiting my customer support so that code can be moved to test for me.   I really hate not being able handle any of my stuff.

Comment: Yes, invoking that method will definitely throw an error in CF10, because it no longer exists in 10. The solution is probably to remove/comment it out. Unless it is being used for something more than debugging.. BTW, can't you just install CF10 on your Dev box? Using different versions on dev=>test>prod is just asking for problems.

Comment: Since I inherited this and the former company is no help on support, I'm assuming I need to buy 10 as opposed to just downloading an upgrade?  I've messed with ColdFusion for a few years, but someone else was the main developer who dealt with such things.  I've done mostly Oracle stuff.   BTW, the code being called that throws this error is a javascript call after clicking on a button.  I have trouble posting code here... I can copy it somewhere and link to it.  Thank you.

Comment: Can CF8 be directly upgraded to CF10?  Just curious.  In a related issue, Oracle cannot be taken from the version of 10 I have directly to 11g.  Just curious if CF is similar.

Comment: The CF Developer version is free. It is limited to two concurrent connections. *Can CF8 be directly upgraded*. With previous versions you could usually do a direct upgrade. However, there were some significant changes in CF10, so I am not sure. FYI - [Stack Overflow works differently than a discussion forum](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). It is more spartan and focused, not a lot of extra chat and "comments" are temporary. I am happy to help if I can, just do not be surprised if the question gets closed or the extended comments deleted ;-)

Comment: Thank you.  Installing 10 as of this moment.